# How can I bring down the interface in the netplan configuration?

Tags: networking, server, netplan

I have an Ubuntu server 18.04 and simple netplan configuration (see below):

```
---
network:
  ethernets:
    ens1:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
      - "192.168.99.1/24"
    ens2:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
      - "172.20.0.82/23"
      gateway4: "172.20.0.1"
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - "172.20.0.62"
  renderer: "networkd"
  version: 2
```

If I run the command: "ip link set dev ens1 down" so the corresponding interface has status "down". If then I run the command "netplan apply" so this interface brings up. How can I change netplan configuration (without committing and lines deleting) in order to have bring down and specified in netplan configuration interfaces not brought up?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve, but mucking about with netplan configs is almost certainly the wrong way to solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is presently no support for defining interface configuration in netplan without `netplan apply` also bringing those interfaces up.
This is a longstanding feature request which required systemd work before it could be implemented.
The work is tracked at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netplan.io/+bug/1664844.

Note that the tasks for Ubuntu bionic have been marked "wontfix"; so this will only be available in netplan in Ubuntu 20.04 and later.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyword optional to reach your goal like below

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
      eno2:
          dhcp4: true
      eno1:
          optional: true
```

More detail can go to http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hirsute/man5/netplan.5.html and look for optional keyword

Comment: the man says -  This   is only supported by networkd.